# Can't print business information from Yelp fusion api

Tags: node.js, yelp

I am using the yelp fusion api to search for a type of business in a location. I can print the whole body correctly but when I try to log just the businesses or a specific parameter of a business I get undefined.

For example, this prints the businesses:

```
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(body);
        res.render('index');
    });
```

I get a large object which looks something like this:

```
{"total": 106, "businesses": [{"transactions": [], "phone": "+15409512483", "name": "The Rivermill", "display_phone": "(540) 951-2483", "price": "$", "review_count": 63, "rating": 4.0, "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/mQbuIZ9uRsXMwIW9UJiHsQ/o.jpg", "id": "the-rivermill-blacksburg", "distance": 511.45787585319994, "location": {"display_address": ["212 Draper Rd", "Blacksburg, VA 24060"], "city": "Blacksburg", "country": "US", "zip_code": "24060", "address1": "212 Draper Rd", "state": "VA", "address2": "", "address3": ""}
```

However, when I try `console.log(body.businesses)` or `console.log(body.businesses[0].name)` both undefined. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the body "object" is actually a string. Try adding

```
console.log("Type:", typeof body)
```

and if it says "Type: string" try

```
const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(bodyObj.businesses);
```

Comment: That indeed was the problem. d'oh! Thanks!